# OpenStack sdk : How to create a server with more than one IP address?

Tags: python, openstack

---

Openstack SDK source code`http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/python-openstacksdk/tree/openstack/compute/v2/server.py`

> #A dictionary of addresses this server can be accessed through.
>   The dictionary contains keys #such as `private` and `public`,
>   each containing a list of dictionaries for addresses of that type.
>   #The addresses are contained in a dictionary with keys `addr`
>   and `version`, which is either 4 or #6 depending on the protocol
>   of the IP address. *Type: dict*

addresses = resource2.Body('addresses', type=dict)

---

My code:

```
 def create_server(conn):
    print("Create Server:")

    image = conn.compute.find_image("cirros")
    flavor = conn.compute.find_flavor("m1.tiny")
    network = conn.network.find_network("test")

    server = conn.compute.create_server(
            name="test", image_id=image.id, flavor_id=flavor.id,
            **addresses={"private":[
                            {"addr":"129.0.1.101","version":4},
                            {"addr":"129.0.1.103","version":4}
                            ]},**
            networks=[{"uuid": network.id}])

    server = conn.compute.wait_for_server(server)
```

Where am I wrong?